# Crash report from an app that I didn't install and that was executed from a non-existing path

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, crash, path, disk-volume

I was reviewing the crash reports in the Console app earlier and I found a very strange crash report from few days ago.

An extract can be found below:

```
Process:               Champlist [2372]
Path:                  /Volumes/VOLUME/*/Champlist.app/Contents/MacOS/Champlist
Identifier:            AwesomeStudio.Champlist
Version:               1.6.6 (1.6.6)
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Champlist [2372]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-05-14 13:20:02.047 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.6 (15G22010)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        0DEDA68F-131F-58D0-77DE-07F1EADEB7CF


Time Awake Since Boot: 6200 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: NSColor)'
```

Not only I never installed Champlist (that based on a Google search is used with a hackintosh, and mine is a 2009 unibody MacBook) but also the path of the executable doesn't exist?!?

I don't have a volume named "VOLUME" and what is the wildcard after that?

```
/Volumes/VOLUME/*/Champlist.app/Contents/MacOS/Champlist
```

If I list all the volumes from terminal (including the hidden ones), this is what I've got:

```
$ ls -a /Volumes
.       ..      .DS_Store   Mac     MobileBackups   Windows
```

Does anybody have an explanation for this?

Comment: Might it have run from inside a DMG? I would certainly do a search for this app.

Comment: @benwiggy: Good idea. I have checked the system log and nothing has been mounted between system boot and the time of the crash. I also did a search for the app both via spotlight and via "find" in terminal and had no results..